# Ajax communication between AWS Beanstalk and S3 Server

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We recently moved to S3 from another hosting provider. We have a S3 bucket which has HTML files and a Beanstalk Bucket which holds all the APIs which is generated by PHP. I am facing CORS issue while communicating with the PHP file using AJAX from S3.

I have placed an `.htaccess` file in the directory of the PHP files which allows CORS. But it does not seems to work. The same worked with the other hosting provider.

The script in `.htaccess` file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

How can I make requests from S3 to Beanstalk without getting CORS errors?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail how it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: have you tried [this documentation page on amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) ?

Comment: Tried to make the question more explicit

Comment: Hey Thankyou citizen. 
dvhh, I tried looking into the reference URL provided by you. All good but they have not specified where to place the xml file :/